# Is there a way to make PIL thumbnail fixed only one dimension and aspect ratio?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two images which have 339 x 1000 px and 6000 x 4000 px and I want to make them both to have **256px width,** with maintaining proportions (aspect ratio).

But the command from PIL libary:

```
img.thumbnail((256, 256))
```

Makes them exactly:

1. 256x87 px
2. 171x256 px

I cannot pass only one parameter. How to set only custom **width** and make it thumbnail with aspect ratio?

I guess the funcion behavior is when the ratio is >1 then it sets properly height, when <1 then proper width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the factor of reduction necessary for the correct width and apply it to the height:

```
from PIL import Image

# Create some representative images
tall = Image.new("L",(339,1000))
wide = Image.new("L",(6000,4000))

tall_s = tall.resize((256,tall.height*256//tall.width))
wide_s = wide.resize((256,wide.height*256//wide.width))
```

Which results in this:

```
tall_s <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=256x755 at 0x7FE2F1369D30>

wide_s <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=256x170 at 0x7FE3003F9370>
```

Comment: I've got stretched image from your solution, so I decided to calculate proportion myself to recall math from school and I get equasion not (tall.height*256//tall.width) but (tall.width*256//tall.heigth) for width, I edited code and now it's working, do you know why it could be?

Comment: I had width and height interchanged. Sorry, please try copying my code afresh.